# Kivy: How to identify text lines on RST document

Tags: python, dynamic, kivy, markup, kivy-language

I'm trying to build my own Rich Text Editor in Kivy since it doesn't already exist. My approach right now is to have the marked-up text stored in a textinput box, and the rendered text displayed in an RST document. I have a bind such that any time the text changes, the RST document updates. Link to image: [Top shows textinput with plain text. Bottom shows rendered text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XVvgB.png)

Right now, I'm having a problem translating clicks on the RST document to the corresponding cursor position on the text editor. I have the x-axis identification working properly, but not the y-axis. For *any line* that I click on for the sample RST document, my cursor is always placed on the last line. Code is shown below

```
class Rendered(RstDocument):
    def __init__(self, text="", **kwargs):
        super(Rendered, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.text = text

class TextArea(TextInput):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(TextArea, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.text = "Filler text"

class Editor(BoxLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Editor, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        self.txt = TextArea()
        self.rst = Rendered(self.txt.text)
        self.txt.bind(text=self.updateRST)

        self.orientation = "vertical"
        self.add_widget(self.txt)
        self.add_widget(self.rst)
        self.rst.render()

    def focusInput(self, *args):
        self.txt.focus = True

    def updateRST(self, *args):
        self.rst.text = self.txt.text

    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        if self.rst.collide_point(*touch.pos):
            #Get mouse click
            coord = self.rst.to_window(*touch.pos)
            #Get new cursor position using mouse click
            newCoord = self.txt.get_cursor_from_xy(coord[0]-5.4,coord[1])
            #Set new cursor position
            self.txt.cursor = (newCoord[0],newCoord[1])
```

I'm using the `to_window()` function to get the click position since it was the closest to the expected position. I used the constant of `5.4` to refine the x-axis position. But `newCoord`[1] always returns the last line of the `textinput`. Part of the problem is that the coordinate system starts in the bottom-left. My y-values are always extraordinarily large when clicking on the first few lines, which is why I think this behavior is occurring, but if I use `to_local` instead of `to_window`, even though the y-coord values start at zero next to the text, the returned line value remains to be the max. How do I fix this?

If you have any advice on how else I can make a rich text editor (i.e., associating the cursor position using a different technique), I would love to hear it! Right now, I can identify the correct x-axis position if there's no markup. If there is, I can just increment the cursor position right for each markup symbol present, but for more complicated markup (like bullet points), this hack might not work so well.

**EDIT**
I realized that, since the text input is stored at the top, it's y-coordinates are far larger than the RST document's y-coordinates. If I place the RST document adjacent to the TextInput, the y-coordinate identification works perfectly, but not the x-coordinate. Ideally, I could just hide the TextInput and have the RST doc on top of it, but I didn't know how to do this. The only way I could think of was to not use `add_widget(TextInput)` to begin with, but then neither of the coordinates were matching up (regardless of whether I used `to_window`, `to_widget`, etc.).

Comment: Hi, do you already have a solution to this as I am looking for a kivy embedded rst editor? I noticed you found somebody else working on this topic: https://www.reddit.com/r/learnpython/comments/4ltt24/kivy_create_a_rich_text_editor/

Comment: Still no solution from my side. Please reply to that Reddit post and perhaps the other person will have had an update.